# Is it centos.pkgs.org website equal to mirror.centos.org in CentOS?

Tags: centos, repository

Recently installed CentOS from `CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1503-01.iso` has a repo file that contains:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

The baseurl is something like "http://mirror.centos.org/centos/".

Is the url equal to [centos.pkg.org](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/zbar-0.10-27.el7.x86_64.rpm.html)?

If not, how to add "centos.pkgs.org" to repo file? add another baseurl as "baseurl=http://centos.pkgs.org"?

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/puias-x86_64/GraphicsMagick-1.3.28-1.sdl7.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: Just for the added information.
According to the discussion [here](https://forum.linuxfoundation.org/discussion/6361/project-pkgs-org). 
[pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org) seems to be a Linux Foundation project.

Answer (score 1):

Some packages in *centos.pkgs.org* refer to *mirror.centos.org/centos* i.e. [389-ds-base-1.3.8.4-15.el7.x86_64.rpm](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/389-ds-base-1.3.8.4-15.el7.x86_64.rpm.html), but some packages is independent and doesn't included in one of the [Official repositories](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories).

**GraphicsMagick** in your case isn't official package and stores at *springdale.math.ias.edu*.

*Install Howto* section in *pkg.org* has instruction about install steps. Some packages include step that involve adding **thirdparty repository** (in your own riscs).

Adding "baseurl=http://centos.pkgs.org" to repo file is wrong. *centos.pkgs.org* is package aggregator and doesn't contain packages directly.

Look at the Official repositories (involve it by installing it as regular package) or include thirdparty repos like *PUIAS* (in your case **GraphicsMagick** located there) by following the [PUIAS repo instractions](http://springdale.math.ias.edu/wiki/YumRepositories7).